# Ubuntu 11.04 graphics problem

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, ubuntu-11.04, integrated-graphics, ubuntu-unity

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 with switchable graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M and Intel integrated Sandy Bridge graphics.

My computer boots fine from the Ubuntu 11.04 live CD into the Unity desktop. However when I install to the hard drive, it gets a black screen on boot. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[May be redirection solves your problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634068)

1. Install Lucid server edition by its textual installer.
2. Redirect output of the laptop to another regular LCD monitor
   (because the laptop's monitor is unreadable now).
3. sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
4. Install the proper nvidia driver (Systems->Administration->Hardware
   Drivers)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing by switchable graphics it's got onboard graphics and an extra card aswell.

Try disabling the onboard graphics in the bios, be sure you know how to reset bios before hand though incase your video card ever fails. Then install ubuntu and hopefully because there's just one video device presented to ubuntu on the install there won't be an issue.

Comment: Good idea, the only problem is if I shut off a graphics card in BIOS then Windows won't be able to use it either (in my experience Ubuntu is nowhere near robust enough to run as my only OS, so I need to dual-boot. No netflix?! plus gnome is slow as hell compared to Win7).  I eventually got it all to work using some ridiculous combination of 3 different tutorials, and then a week later the graphics stopped booting again for no apparent reason.  In any case, I'll just stick to running Linux in a VM for the time being.  I guess I'm just not a "Linux guy"